# CKEditor V4 with bb plugin and video plugin, can not change value

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

I am trying to build a comment system with [ckeditor V4](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4/) in combination with the [bb plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/bbcode) (changed) and this [video plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/videodetector) (changed).

Now, I can submit the comment to the system but when I try to edit the post it gets stuck. The user needs to click on the post so the post changes in the CKEditor, an ajax request is asking for the original HTML and pass them in the editor.

When I remove the video plugin it works, but I do not see why it's not working with the plugin. Can someone give me an idea of what I did wrong?

I do not know how the plugin's interact with the editor, what part of the code do you need/handles the init of the code? (i do not want to post the full code because many form's hate this action)

Thanks for your time of reading it.

Comment: Could you please put a part of the code, otherwise it might be difficult to answer

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the video plugin code, we can see that it does simply embed the video via an iframe L49 in videodetector-master/dialogs/videoDialog.js :

```
        var iframe = new CKEDITOR.dom.element('iframe');
        iframe.setAttribute('src', url);
        iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
        p.append(iframe);
```

The problem comes from the `bbcode` plugin, as it doesn't support the `iframe` tag created by the video plugin, so it crashes when trying to translate the video iframe into a bbcode tag.

By inspecting the plugin code, we can see it's straightforward to add support for the `iframe` tag:

Plugin file: bbcode/plugin.js
Add the iframe tag in L29:

```
var bbcodeMap = { iframe: 'span', b: 'strong', u: 'u', /* rest of tags here */}
```

Add the check for special handling (same as the `img` tag) in L164:

```
if ( part == 'email' || part == 'img' || part == 'iframe' )
```

Add the change needed for the preview (from bbcode to html) in L618:

```
} else if ( bbcode == 'iframe' ) {
    element.name = 'iframe';
    element.attributes.src = element.children[ 0 ].value;
    element.children = [];
}
```

Add the change needed for the output (from html to bbcode) in L730:

```
} else if ( tagName == 'iframe' ) {
    element.isEmpty = 0;
    var src = attributes.src;
    element.children = [ new CKEDITOR.htmlParser.text( src ) ];
}
```

Here is a demo fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s17mjwdz/